Derivative of Left Jacobian $J_l(\theta) $ from $ \text{SO}(3) $ with respect to Rotation Vector
I am working on a problem related to the Special Orthogonal group $ \text{SO}(3) $ and the left Jacobian $ J_l(\boldsymbol{\theta}) $, which maps a tangent space on the manifold to a rotation vector $ \boldsymbol{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^3 $. Specifically, I am interested in the following function:
$$
f(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = J_l(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \mathbf{v}
$$
where $ J_l(\boldsymbol{\theta}) $ is the left Jacobian for $ \text{SO}(3) $, and $ \mathbf{v} $ is a fixed 3D vector.
The left Jacobian $ J_l(\boldsymbol{\theta}) $ is expressed as:
$$
J_l(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = I_3 + \frac{1 - \cos(\theta)}{\theta^2} \boldsymbol{\theta}^{\times} + \frac{\theta - \sin(\theta)}{\theta^3} \boldsymbol{\theta}^{\times} \boldsymbol{\theta}^{\times}
$$
where $ \theta = \|\boldsymbol{\theta}\| $ and $ \boldsymbol{\theta}^{\times} $ is the skew-symmetric matrix of $ \boldsymbol{\theta} $, representing the cross-product operation.
I am trying to compute the Jacobian of $ f(\boldsymbol{\theta}) $ with respect to $ \boldsymbol{\theta} $, i.e.,
$$
\frac{\partial f(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}
$$
Is there a known closed-form expression or established method for finding this Jacobian? Any references or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
